# Error Message (Query Pattern Missing) When Trying to Publish Google Action

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I get error message when try to publish actions and submit it for review. It says query pattern missing on default welcome intent. My query pattern is not missing at all. Can someone please explain to me why I get this error and how to fix it so I can submit my action? I have submitted my question to tech support and ofcourse nobody has ever responded to my message.  Thank you for any help that you can provide.

Here is screenshot of the default welcome intent.

[image]

Thank you for any help that you can provide.

Comment: This is a major problem and without solving this problem, we can't proceed :-!
@Prisoner Could you please be kind to help me also!

Comment: Can we see a screen shot of the error message as well (and if you can show the page where you're getting the message, it might help as well). I'm trying to figure out how to duplicate the problem and can't yet. And Google won't be able to respond unless they see a clear way to duplicate - the more info you can provide the better.

Comment: @Prisoner I will explain it properly. I am creating a fresh question

Comment: @Prisoner I have figured out the solution!

Comment: What is the solution @Prisoner. Please let me know as I get nothing but error message upon submission which says query pattern is missing from custom intent.  What do I do (step by step) how to fix this?  I am not wanting to do an alpha or a beta (which environment mentioned by Raghav Joshi suggested). I just want to submit.

Comment: @MACT I can't speak for Prisoner on this, but my personal experience with this issue is two-fold. One was the language issue (no training phrases supplied for the Spanish invocations of the welcome intent) and the second was the fact that I was putting an explicit intent in the implicit intents list for the Assistant Integration Settings, which also triggers, annoyingly, the same error message.

Answer (score 9):

I was getting this error because i had added two languages(English and  Hindi) and i haven't added any training phrases for Hindi. So either add training phrase for all languages or remove the language u don't need in the intents. This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 7):

I got this error because I had an intent in the "implicit invocation" list that was triggered by an event from the fulfillment server.

The implicit invocation list should only contain deep-linkable intents such as "OK Google, ask Personal Chef for a hot soup recipe". Not callbacks/returned events without a spoken trigger.

You can edit the implicit invocations under Integrations > Google Assistant.

Comment: The Welcome Intent is automatically added as an explicit intent in the Assistant integrations settings, so this may be confusing for SO users landing here for the use case in the question. The error in the use case for this question is more likely the training phrases for a second language missing. Regardless, this answer is useful as the same error message comes up for both scenarios, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50537617/dialogflow-actions-on-google-dialogflow-helper-intents-nodejs-tutorial-query)

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what's the problem and how to fix it. 
The problem is occurring because at once, you had not input the query and you would have tried for submitting the project but the error prompted. After writing the queries, you again went to Actions Console for submitting the project but again it showed the same prompt.

Now the problem which occurred is that actions console was not updated with the dialog flow. To update the console, you have to go to your project settings and then go to 'Environment'. There you have to create an environment and then publish it. Then head towards actions console, there you will be able to submit you action. 
Learn about environment [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/submit-app#dialogflow_versioning).

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying at all. Can you please explain step by step what I need to do?