# DialogFlow Actions on Google: dialogflow-helper-intents-nodejs Tutorial - Query Pattern is missing for Custom Intent

Tags: actions-on-google

I am attempting to use the tutorial located here: https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-helper-intents-nodejs

I have created an entirely new agent to make sure none of my existing intent settings are causing this. I import the file helper-intents-examples.zip and modify NOTHING in ANY of the intents. I go to Integrations->Integration Settings, add all of the intents, and hit test, and I get the following error for every single second turn intent:

> Request contains an invalid argument. Query pattern is missing for
>   custom intent 'X'

I have found no tutorial that doesn't result in this error for the confirmation/rejection/permission response intents. This error is incredibly generic and unhelpful in solving this issue.

Comment: Kyle, are you still having this problem?

Comment: Yes. Again, I literally just import the intents that are in that zip file and hit "test" and it throws that error for every single second turn intent.

Comment: I just added a new intent and tried to add the Integration intent, so I can see it in the actions on google console and I get this error.

Comment: Since people are finding this and not understanding what's going on, let me explain.

This error occurs when the training phrases are empty. Every intent has to have training phrases in ALL locals. If you get this error, try to look at see if maybe you forgot in a different language. Google is horrible at explaining what errors actually mean.